# Comparing whether two sets of total arrival of customers is significant

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Forgive me if this is a basic stats question.

I want to compare whether two distributions for total arrival of people are different for 2 consecutive years. I only have this aggregated data.

An example of my data is:

[image: Distribution]

What distribution is this and how can I use this to compare against another similar looking distribution to test for difference?

Thank you

Comment: You need to choose a specific hypothesis test in advance in order for "significant" to be even be defined -- i.e. an affect appears significant _relative to the assumptions of the model underlying the given hypothesis test_. So you are asking at least two questions: (1) what model (and corresponding hypothesis test) should I use (2) how to apply the chosen hypothesis test. (2) can't be answered well without answering (1) first.

Comment: It's possible to test whether two distributions differ without specifying what that distribution is. Is "total arrival of people" a count of people, or do you mean something else by "arrival". Are these daily or weekly data or something?

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very small as it seems) sample probably following a certain distribution.

It looks like an **exponential distribution**.

But be aware that you only have a few samples and that an exponential *may* be a not-too-bad approximation which does not resemble the true original distribution.

For more confidence, more data points would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to know is the hypothesis to test against. In your case that's already non-trivial.

From looking at your data I would assume the underlying distribution is actually a mixture of distributions. From what I see, you may assume a mixture of Poisson distrubutions.

With that assumption you can build a model which most likely generated the data. For that you could use the expectation maximization algorithm ([See](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/bmmalone/probabilistic-models-spring-2014/mixture-of-poissons.pdf)). Having this model you can calculate the likelihood of the other data (i.e the other year). If the likelihood does not significantly drop you can assume that the the real world which generated the data has not changed either.